# Way to automatically determine word context/meaning in Python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a Python list of words about different topics (specifically subreddit names). I need to filter out only subreddits about programming, like "linux", "Python", "lisp", "programming", "ProgrammerHumor" etc. (notice the lack of consistency with capital letters). Is there any automatic way to do it, e. g. with NLTK, or do I have to do it by hand?

EDIT:
Apparently my initial question was a bit unclear. So I have a long list of possible subreddit names and I want to filter out only those that have to do with programming. **I don't know which ones are those** - there may be programming languages names ("lisp", "Python"), or general programming stuff ("programming", "ProgrammerHumor"), or anything programming-related ("LearningMachineLearning, "linux"). Is there any way to extract those ones automatically, possibly with NLP, based on a word meaning/context, or do I have to do it by hand?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: The answer I gave below does precisely what you say...

Comment: @HaydenEastwood your answer supposes that I have this list of words stems. I do not. I need "programming-related" words from list of generic words. "cats" or "AskReddit" is not programming-related, "lisp" is.

Comment: Ok - a really crucial point that you missed out in your initial post! Definitely an NLK problem then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. But if the question is whether you can match words that are contaminated with capital letters, you should just convert everything to lowercase and then do a *regex* match.

In your case this might look something like:

Step 1: install regex:

```
pip install regex
```

Step 2: write the code:

---

```
import regex as re
list_of_stuff = ['Python', 'linux', 'lisp', 'programming', 'ProgrammerHumor']
thing_to_find = 'program'
mult3 = map(lambda x: x.find(thing_to_find), list(map(str.lower, list_of_stuff)))
print (list(mult3)) # [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0] -1 = no match, 0 = match
```

In the above, the output is:

```
[-1, -1, -1, 0, 0]
```

In which -1 indicates an index of no match, and 0 indicates a match.

Answer (score 0):

Use a similarity method like spacy() to check this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).